# difference between $_SERVER and apache_note

Tags: php, apache, location, geoip

I need to get the user country code and I've managed this by using both

```
apache_note('GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE')
```

and

```
$_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE']
```

Is there any reason why I should use one of these over the other or are they both the exact same? They output the same result and as can be seen have the same index key so I assume it comes from the same place, is this correct?

I tried using the php function `geoip_country_code_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR])` but it just returns `null` (geoip is installed) each time whereas the `$_SERVER` and `apache_note` have only not worked when I routed through switzerland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better practice to use `$_SERVER` because if your application will scaled you might consider switching to `nginx` for performance and there `apache_note` function might not be available while `$_SERVER` will be available under every server.

From documentation:

`The main use for apache_note() is to pass information from one module to another within the same request.`

Comment: Perfect explanation :)